# Momoko Ping Setup

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, tornado, psycopg2, momoko

I'm new to Tornado and Momoko (i was using queries before) , I keep getting this error when I run this method:

`psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name \"pg\" to address: No address associated with hostname`

i know that the host works because i have made successful connections with queries.

here is how i am setting it up (its a simple checker function to make sure the connection still works):

```
def __init__(self, event, frequency, params):
    super().__init__(event, frequency, params)
    # uri of PGDB
    self.dsn ='dbname=%s user=%s password=%s host=%s port=%s' % (configuration["postgre"][0]["dbName"],
                                                                 configuration["postgre"][0]["userName"],
                                                                 configuration["postgre"][0]["password"],
                                                                 configuration["postgre"][0]["host"],
                                                                 configuration["postgre"][0]["port"])
    logging.info(self.dsn)
    # creates actual link to DB
    self.Pg_Loop = IOLoop

    self.host = configuration["postgre"][0]["host"]

@gen.coroutine
def check(self):
    try:
        loop = self.Pg_Loop
        pool = momoko.Connection(dsn=self.dsn, ioloop=loop)
        future = yield pool.connect()
        yield future.result()
        data = {'host': self.host, 'status': events.STATUS_OK}
    except (PartiallyConnectedError, PoolError, InternalError, DatabaseError, OperationalError):
        data = {'host': self.host, 'status': events.STATUS_FAIL, 'error': traceback.format_exc()}
    self.save(data)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should yield future and then your function is resumed, its result would be available

```
future = momoko.Connection(dsn=self.dsn, ioloop=loop).connect()
yield future
conn = future.result()
```

or a shorter version:

```
conn = yield momoko.Connection(dsn=self.dsn, ioloop=loop).connect()
```